In IntelliJ(2024.1.1) with the Scala Plugin(2024.1.20), Main.main is Failing with "Could not find or load main class org.public_domain.main"
UPDATE:
Nestled deep within the large accepted answer is the way to fix this; i.e. rename the method from main to something else, or rename the object Main to something else.
The conflict is a case insensitivity issue on the Windows (or MacOS) file system where having both the object and the @main marked method be the same case-insensitive value creates an issue.
Hopefully, the IntelliJ Scala Plugin guys can add this to their awesome "automated warnings system", so no one else falls into this Scala 3 rabbit hole.

UPDATE Older:
Upon further investigation...This works in Scastie strongly suggesting it is an IntelliJ Scala Plugin issue (Jetbrains YouTrack ticket).

After creating a new Scala 3.3.3 project in IntelliJ(2024.1.1) with the Scala Plugin(2024.1.20), my "braceless syntax" Main.main method is failing with "Could not find or load main class org.public_domain.main".
I must be missing something totally obvious. However, after an hour of tinkering with it, I give up. What am I missing?
Here's the ONLY file I've created in the entire project, and upon which I clicked the small green arrow in the left tray of the main method to select "Run org.public_domain.main".
package org.public_domain

object Main:
  @main def main(): Unit =
    println("Hello World!")

SideNote: I'm noticing IntelliJ isn't properly referring to org.public_domain.Main.main as the method I am running.
BTW, if I comment out object Main: (which I very much do not want to do), it runs fine.
IOW, this works fine:
package org.public_domain

@main def main(): Unit =
  println("Hello World!")


It's crap like this that makes it so hard for someone starting out with Scala to stick with it. The number of silly little technical tangents I end up going upon as I build up a Scala project essentially leaves me frustrated as I never quite get into the hyper-productive "flow" state. And I both LOVE Scala and have been advocating for Scala since 2011/Jan.


If the package is org.public_domain in

package org.public_domain

object Main:
  @main def main(): Unit =
    println("Hello World!")

then this file Main.scala should be placed at /path/to/yourproject/src/main/scala/org/public_domain/Main.scala


Then running sbt run from the root of your project prints Hello World!

$ sbt run
[info] welcome to sbt 1.10.0 (Amazon.com Inc. Java 21.0.3)
[info] loading global plugins from /home/dmitin/.sbt/1.0/plugins
[info] loading project definition from /path/to/yourproject/project
[info] loading settings for project root from build.sbt ...
[info] set current project to yourproject (in build file:/path/to/yourproject/)
[info] compiling 1 Scala source to /path/to/yourproject/target/scala-3.3.3/classes ...
[warn] -- Warning: /path/to/yourproject/src/main/scala/org/public_domain/Main.scala:3:7 
[warn] 3 |object Main:
[warn]   |       ^
[warn]   |object Main differs only in case from class main in package org.public_domain. Such classes will overwrite one another on case-insensitive filesystems.
[warn] one warning found
[info] running org.public_domain.main 
Hello World!
[success] Total time: 3 s, completed 18 мая 2024 г., 20:06:05



Please notice the warning object Main differs only in case from class main in package org.public_domain. Such classes will overwrite one another on case-insensitive filesystems. If you are on a case-insensitive filesystem (for example Windows or MacOS) then change the name of your method, for example

package org.public_domain

object Main:
  @main def run(): Unit =
    println("Hello World!")


Look in the directory target/scala-3.3.3/classes/org/public_domain. There should be created several classes (with object name and @main-annotated method name):

$ cd target/scala-3.3.3/classes/org/public_domain
$ ls
main.class  Main.class  Main$.class  main.tasty  Main.tasty

(or run.class instead of main.class if you renamed the method).


Getting started: https://docs.scala-lang.org/getting-started/index.html

Sbt directory structure: https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Directories.html




the IntelliJ Scala plugin is incorrectly invoking org.public_domain.main as opposed to correctly invoking org.public_domain.Main.main

I'm glad if you resolved your issues but I'm afraid you could misinterpret your findings. At least I can see some confusion. There are several classes here: Main.class, Main$.class, main.class (or run.class if we renamed the method). Main.class and Main$.class represent the object, main.class represents the @main-annotated method. It's exactly the class org.public_domain.main that should be called (it has runnable method public static void main(java.lang.String[])), not org.public_domain.Main (it doesn't have main(String[])). You can see methods in classes with javap:
$ cd /path/to/yourproject/target/scala-3.3.3/classes/org/public_domain/
$ ls
main.class  Main.class  Main$.class  main.tasty  Main.tasty

$ cd /path/to/yourproject/target/scala-3.3.3/classes
$ javap org.public_domain.Main
Compiled from "Main.scala"
public final class org.public_domain.Main {
  public static void main();
}

$ javap org.public_domain.Main$
Compiled from "Main.scala"
public final class org.public_domain.Main$ implements java.io.Serializable {
  public static final org.public_domain.Main$ MODULE$;
  public static {};
  public void main();
}

$ javap org.public_domain.main
Compiled from "Main.scala"
public final class org.public_domain.main {
  public org.public_domain.main();
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}

If you run your code with IntelliJ IDEA rather than with sbt (I recommended the latter) then you can configure what to run in the menu Run -> Edit configurations



IntelliJ writes the exact command that is run:

By default it's collapsed. If you click it expands. For me it's
/media/data/jdk1.8.0_351/bin/java -javaagent:/media/data/idea-IU-241.15989.150/lib/idea_rt.jar=38299:/media/data/idea-IU-241.15989.150/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /media/data/jdk1.8.0_351/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/media/data/jdk1.8.0_351/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/media/data/jdk1.8.0_351/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/media/data/jdk1.8.0_351/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/media/data/jdk1.8.0_351/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/media/data/jdk1.8.0_351/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/media/data/jdk1.8.0_351/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/media/data/jdk1.8.0_351/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/media/data/jdk1.8.0_351/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/media/data/jdk1.8.0_351/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/media/data/jdk1.8.0_351/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/media/data/jdk1.8.0_351/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/media/data/jdk1.8.0_351/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/media/data/jdk1.8.0_351/jre/lib/jce.jar:/media/data/jdk1.8.0_351/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/media/data/jdk1.8.0_351/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/media/data/jdk1.8.0_351/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/media/data/jdk1.8.0_351/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/media/data/jdk1.8.0_351/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/media/data/jdk1.8.0_351/jre/lib/resources.jar:/media/data/jdk1.8.0_351/jre/lib/rt.jar:/media/data/Projects2/scala3demo2/target/scala-3.3.3/classes:/home/dmitin/.cache/coursier/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.13.12/scala-library-2.13.12.jar:/home/dmitin/.cache/coursier/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala3-library_3/3.3.3/scala3-library_3-3.3.3.jar org.public_domain.main

Now it can be shortened to
$ cd /path/to/yourproject/target/scala-3.3.3/classes
$ java -classpath .:/path_to_jars/scala-library-2.13.12.jar:/path_to_jars/scala3-library_3-3.3.3.jar org.public_domain.main

Hello World!


While I appreciate your thorough answer, it doesn't solve the core issue I identified (clicking on the green arrow and selecting run from within Intellij). It does, however, corroborate the conclusion I had tentatively reached after trying the Main class in Scastie; i.e. the IntelliJ Scala plugin is incorrectly invoking org.public_domain.main as opposed to correctly invoking org.public_domain.Main.main.

Ah. I just saw your renaming of the main method suggestion. And THAT does fix the issue.

@chaotic3quilibrium So you are on Windows or MacOS

You correctly guessed that I was on Windows.

I don't understand where the main.class came from. I get the Main.class and Main$.class. However, main is a method in Main, not a class. So, what exactly is going on behind the @main annotation? Is it generating a hidden nested main Scala class, as your final screenshot suggests? If so, even with my current extensive Scala experience, I wouldn't have guess that for the life of me.

BTW, in the version of IntelliJ I am using on Windows, I don't have sbt available at Terminal (generates a weird error). Instead, I have to use the "sbt shell" tab available along the bottom rail (next to Git, Run, Profiler, Build, Services, etc.). And when I bring "sbt shell" up and wait for it to complete initialization, the command to get it to do what you are doing at the terminal is "run", not "sbt run". It turns out, typing "sbt{space}" in the "sbt shell" is entirely unnecessary. That shell presumes the "sbt{space}" prefix for every entered command.

@chaotic3quilibrium You can install sbt outside IDE https://www.scala-sbt.org/

Tysvm for adding that. It appears you are confirming that the @main annotation is actually causing an entire object main Scala class to be built and compiled in the background. IOW, that is the root cause for the conflict. And it is why renaming it to run changes it to be an object run Scala class being built and compiled in the background which resolves the conflict.

@chaotic3quilibrium If you install sbt outside IDE then in the terminal outside IDE you can execute sbt some_command like sbt clean, sbt compile, sbt run. Or you can start sbt in interactive mode with just sbt and execute clean, compile, run there. If you execute sbt some_command in the terminal inside IDE or some_command in sbt shell of IDE then IDE can intercept your command (IDE has /home/dmitin/.local/share/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2024.1/Scala/launcher/sbt-launch.jar in its installation).
